Adding WPF Page to WPF Window
I am making a common element like a button, so I made it in a WPF Page I designed it and I just want to know what the best way is to add that page in a WPF Window in the designer.
    <WrapPanel RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5" Margin="0,0,754,0">
        
        
        <Button Content="" Height="36" Width="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                local:ButtonHelper.HoverImage="/Assets/Utility/menu_hovered.png">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="5" Y="5"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Utility/menu.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        
        
    </WrapPanel>
</Page>

this is just something I added in the WPF Page
I have tried adding Content Controller, but I can't understand it

Rather than using a page, it'd be more usual to define a template as a resource and just use a button with that template wherever you want your button. A button is a content control so you coukd alternatively put something in a button has a picture of whatever you prefer. Button background might not work as you seem to expect. There's a mouse over effect makes a blue rectangle appear. Content might be more appropriate here.

<Grid x:Name="viewSpace">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Frame Name="mainFrm" Grid.Row="0" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
<!--only if you want to hide the nav bar keep it hidden-->
</Grid>

Setting the mainFrm.Content in your code behind to a page will change the content on the window.
I would recommend not using a content control for WPF Pages. ContentControls work best with UserControls if I'm not mistaken.
This is a good question found on stack overflow with some good answers.
Window vs Page vs UserControl for WPF navigation?
In the highest rated answer ContentArea.Content = new MyUserControl(); Is how they recommend Custom user control navigation with ContentControls. I don't know the ultimate answer what is best but I have always personally used pages for navigation since it works well with the MVVM structure.
